# Android Beacon stopped scanning after app is closed (swiping it off on the recent apps list)

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, beacon, altbeacon

I am using [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) to scan ibeacon. In these codes, it will scan ibeacon in the background using BootstrapNotifier interface. Once an iBeacon is detected, RangeNotifier interface kicks in and display the beacon information in textview. When I close this app (by swiping it off on the recent apps list) , the background scan stopped. By right it should not stop scanning based on the example [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html). Below are the codes. Appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.budakgigibesi.ibeacon_scan;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;

import java.util.Collection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BootstrapNotifier, BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        //enable beacon features///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);    // disable JobScheduler-based scans (used on Android 8+)
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);    // set the time between each scan to be 1 hour (3600 seconds)
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);    // set the duration of the scan to be 1.1 seconds

        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion", null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);    // wake up the app when a beacon is seen

        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);  //This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%

        beaconManager.bind(this);   //for beacon RangeNotifier
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    //altbeacon bootstrapnotifier///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_tv);
        mTextView.setText( "found a beacon");

        // 
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);  //Tells the BeaconService to start looking for beacons that match the passed Region object, and providing updates on the estimated mDistance every seconds while beacons in the Region are visible.
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("RangeNotifier", "Can't start ranging");
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //altbeacon BeaconConsumer///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        if (beacons.size() > 0) {
            Log.i("beaconconsumer", "didRangeBeaconsInRegion called with beacon count:  "+beacons.size());
            for (Beacon b : beacons) {
                Log.i("beaconconsumer", "The first beacon " + b.toString() + " is about " + b.getDistance() + " meters away.");
                TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_tv);
                mTextView.setText( "The first beacon " + b.toString() + " is about " + b.getDistance() + " meters away.");
            }
        }catch (RemoteException e) {   }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (beaconManager.isBound(this)) beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (beaconManager.isBound(this)) beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
    }




}
```

and found some errors in the logcat

```
10-30 13:24:40.263 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 4096
10-30 13:24:40.263 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanResult() - address=7C:64:56:83:5E:71, rssi=-86
10-30 13:24:40.323 7928-7945/com.example.budakgigibesi.ibeacon_scan D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
10-30 13:24:40.323 14712-14847/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue=1
10-30 13:24:40.333 14712-14847/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue empty; stopping scan
10-30 13:24:40.333 14712-14847/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_scan
10-30 13:24:40.333 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btgattc_handle_event: Event 1003
10-30 13:24:40.343 14712-14723/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
10-30 13:24:40.343 14712-14723/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_unregister_app
10-30 13:24:40.353 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btgattc_handle_event: Event 1001
10-30 13:24:40.353 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 1
10-30 13:24:40.363 7928-7945/com.example.budakgigibesi.ibeacon_scan D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
10-30 13:24:40.363 14712-14724/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=6f27a4f0-4631-405a-8651-07c58b62f50d
10-30 13:24:40.373 14712-14724/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_register_app
10-30 13:24:40.373 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btgattc_handle_event: Event 1000
10-30 13:24:40.373 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 0
10-30 13:24:40.373 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=6f27a4f0-4631-405a-8651-07c58b62f50d, clientIf=5
10-30 13:24:40.373 7928-7998/com.example.budakgigibesi.ibeacon_scan D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
10-30 13:24:40.383 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.GattService: startScan() - queue=0
10-30 13:24:40.383 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.GattService: startScan() - adding client=5
10-30 13:24:40.383 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_scan
10-30 13:24:40.383 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btgattc_handle_event: Event 1002
10-30 13:24:40.463 932-14195/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 7928:com.example.budakgigibesi.ibeacon_scan/u0a315 (adj 16): remove task
10-30 13:24:40.673 14712-16859/? D/BtGatt.GattService: Binder is dead - unregistering client (5)!
10-30 13:24:40.673 14712-16859/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue=1
10-30 13:24:40.673 14712-16859/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue empty; stopping scan
10-30 13:24:40.673 14712-16859/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_scan
10-30 13:24:40.673 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btgattc_handle_event: Event 1003
10-30 13:24:40.673 932-1593/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.budakgigibesi.ibeacon_scan/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService in 1000ms
10-30 13:24:40.683 14712-16859/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
10-30 13:24:40.683 14712-16859/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_unregister_app
10-30 13:24:40.683 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btgattc_handle_event: Event 1001
10-30 13:24:40.683 14712-30801/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 1
10-30 13:24:41.204 932-932/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
10-30 13:24:41.204 1189-1189/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
10-30 13:24:41.204 932-932/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
10-30 13:24:41.294 406-1066/? D/QC-QMI: Thread state: conn_id=18, state=RX_THREAD_WAKELOCK_ACQUIRE
10-30 13:24:41.294 406-1066/? D/QC-QMI: Thread state: conn_id=18, state=RX_THREAD_WAIT_READ
10-30 13:24:41.294 406-1066/? D/QC-QMI: Thread state: conn_id=18, state=RX_THREAD_CLIENT_TX
10-30 13:24:41.294 406-1066/? D/QC-QMI: qmi_qmux: TX/RX - RX 95 bytes on conn_id=18
10-30 13:24:41.294 406-1066/? D/QC-QMI: qmuxd: TX message on fd=24, to qmux_client_id=0x3, len=129
10-30 13:24:41.294 406-1066/? D/QC-QMI: Thread state: conn_id=18, state=RX_THREAD_WAKELOCK_RELEASE
10-30 13:24:41.294 406-1066/? D/QC-QMI: Thread state: conn_id=18, state=RX_THREAD_WAIT_POLL
```

Comment: What device model do you see this on?

Comment: @davidgyoung . i am using android 4.4 on Sony xPeria Z

Comment: Can you check it with the stopped app detector mentioned in my answer?  I would be surprised if a big nsme manufacturer like Sony nade this mistake.

Comment: when i use Stopped App Detector, my beacon app was not listed there when i close the app (swiping it off on the recent apps list) . However, the scan still stopped. i noticed there were some errors in the logcat. I have posted the logcat logs as shown above.

Comment: [Using the Android Beacon Library with a foreground service](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html) should solve this problem.

Comment: Are you waiting up to 5 minutes after swiping the app off the screen before expecting detections again?  That's how long it might take if using service scanning (the default in Android 4.4)

Comment: Yes, i waited for 5 minutes but the detection did not start. I think there's something wrong with my codes. Let me check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Among the many customizations that some minor Android manufacturers like to make to the operating system is to customize the task switcher.  Sone do this in a way that makes swiping apps off the screen put the app into the "stopped" state.

On stock Android, swiping apps off the task switcher does not put apps into the stopped state.  Doing a face stop from Settings -> Apps does.  Once an app is in the stopped state it is as if it has never before been launched.  It is not allowed to start itself in response to timers or external events like beacon detections.  A user must msnuslly launch it to get it back out of the stopped app state.

It is unclear if this is an intentional or mistaken change by these manufacturers.   Either way, you cannot do anything about it, unfortunately.

You can check if you have one of these phones by running the [stopped app detector](https://github.com/davidgyoung/stopped-app-detector).

See here for more info:

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/729

Comment: thanks for the tips. looks like i need to ensure the app is not closed. maybe by using notification builder could solve my problem.

Comment: -1 This looks to me like normal Android termination behavior for apps once they are placed in the background. OP has not mentioned any use of a foreground service, so it's entirely possible the system is simply trying to free up resources.

Comment: The OP explicitly said this was after swiping it off the screen.  On Android 4.4 (noted in his comment) the library uses a background service for scanning by default.  Swiping the app off the screen will stop that service for sure, but it should automatically restart in 5 minutes via the AlarmManager if the app is not in the stopped state.

Answer (score 0):

For auto restart to work, you must construct RegionBootstap in the onCreate method of a custom Application class, not an Activity class as you have shown.  The Activity is only started when manually launched, so this will not work to trigger scanning after auto restart after being killed.

Comment: thanks for tips. now i know why the app was not started again. i have corrected the codes as shown in my answer post.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. Below are the corrected codes. I separated it into 2 classes. One is for application class and one for bluetooth scan class. when the app is closed (swiping it off on the recent apps list) , application class (MyApplication) will be started again and start the bluetooth scan class (ScanBT).

MyApplication.java

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {      

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanBT.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent); 
    }


}
```

ScanBT.java

```
public class ScanBT extends AppCompatActivity implements BootstrapNotifier, BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        Log.i("foxy", "ScanBT - i am in onCreateeeeeeeee");

        //enable beacon features///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);    
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);    
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);    

        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion", null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);    

        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);  

        beaconManager.bind(this);   
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    //altbeacon bootstrapnotifier///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i("foxy", "ScanBT - a beacon entered the region");


        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);  
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("RangeNotifier", "Can't start ranging");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {

    }   

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {

    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //altbeacon BeaconConsumer///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        if (beacons.size() > 0) {
            Log.i("foxy", "ScanBT - didRangeBeaconsInRegion called with beacon count:  "+beacons.size());
            for (Beacon b : beacons) {
                Log.i("foxy", "ScanBT - The first beacon " + b.toString() + " is about " + b.getDistance() + " meters away.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a fine solution.